# Xpages get index of repeat in CSJS

Tags: javascript, xpages, repeat

I want to get the index of an repeat in CSJS. I tried to get the repeatID and then get the value, but it is not working.

```
var r="view:_id1:repeat1:"
var val=document.getElementById(r).value.toString();
```

Comment: What do you mean with *index*? The actual position? The rendered HTML? Currently, you are trying to access a non-existing DOM element...

Comment: @SvenHasselbach every repeat control has a indexVar which I've set it to index value. I want to see how many times it repeats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a computed text like this:

```
  <xp:text
        escape="true"
        id="computedFieldIndexVar"
        tagName="input">

        <xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:attr
                name="type"
                value="hidden">
            </xp:attr>
            <xp:attr
             name="value"
             value="#{javascript:var rp:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspDataIterator = getComponent('repeat1');rp.getRowCount()}">
             </xp:attr>
        </xp:this.attrs>
    </xp:text>
```

You can then access the field in CSJS:

```
var r="view:_id1:computedFieldIndexVar"
var val=document.getElementById(r).value
```

The repeat control has the id *repeat1*.